# Is the meaning of "/../" - parent directory standard in URLs?

Tags: url

In many filesystems ".." corresponds to parent directory. How is it with URLs? I saw some examples behaving according to this scheme, but is this a standard (RFC)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course this is a standard http://www.w3.org/Addressing/rfc1808.txt describes it, the `segment/..` is removed iteratively from left to right.

Answer (score 4):

Exactly the same.

http://www.mysite.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/index.html

a link to "../../me.jpg" should give you http://www.mysite.com/dir1/me.jpg

The cod red virus that went round a good number of years back attacked IIS sites because c:\inetpub.. was the document root and if you did a url such as /../../../../windows/cmd.exe%20dir it would execute it!

Comment: I wrote I saw that behaviour, I am even aware of the code red virus:). I am asking if this behaviour is a standard for URLs or if it is just a convention. If it is a standard, I would like a link to standard document definining it (e.g. RFC).

Comment: relative pathing is not inherantly bad, is it a standard? well on windows/unix its a given working part of the OS. If I saw someone write in a link http://mysite.com/dir1/dir2/../dir3/page.html I would probably want a stern word with them though

Comment: I know that... please read my question. I am asking if it is possible for a web to give different results and be "web compliant".

Comment: Depends what you mean by "different results", a website shouldnt let you outside the document tree, going from mysite/folder1 to mysite/folder2 could be 2 entirely different areas, but a url of ../folder2 should still take you there. (I did read your question, but as Ive tried to say, I dont think there is a specific RTC or anything to declare official or otherwise)